# Power set empty set confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So the question is

Let $T = \{a,b\}$ and $S = \{Ø,\{Ø\}\}$.

So what $i$ would assume would be the power set of $T$ is $\{\varnothing,a\}$,  $\{\varnothing,b\}$,  $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{a,b\}$.

However in the result of my teachers they don't mention $\{Ø,b\}\ $ but they do the $\{Ø,a\}\ $ Why is that??

Another thing

The power set of $S$

$\{\{Ø\},Ø\}, \{Ø\}, \{Ø,\{Ø\}\}\}$

What is up with the last one?

And can you have $\{Ø\}$ stranding alone?

Thank u.

Comment: $S=\{\varnothing\},\varnothing\}$ is not well-formed -- it has two } but only one {. Carefully proofread the number and position of brackets with such questions.

Comment: Yeah, thats a mistake by me. But i still dont get the last one that is extactly how it has been written.{Ø,{Ø}}}

Comment: x @ABCCode: Please edit the question to _fix that mistake_, instead of just confirming that it was a mistake. If the "$\{\{Ø\},Ø\}, \{Ø\}, \{Ø,\{Ø\}\}\}$" is verbatim from your book, then it must be a typo -- the brackets don't balance there either.

Comment: Done. What is the correct answer then?

Comment: x @ABC: I fully endorse David Wheeler's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little puzzled by your description of $\mathcal{P}(T)$.

If $T = \{a,b\}$, then its power set is:

$\mathcal{P}(T) = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}\}$.

Similarly if $S = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, we have:

$\mathcal{P}(S) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$

This is just a confusing-looking mess obtained by replacing the symbol $a$ with $\emptyset$, and the symbol $b$ with $\{\emptyset\}$.

The elements of sets may very well be sets themselves, leading to "bracket confusion".

Comment: "The elements of sets may very well be sets themselves" — indeed, at least in standard set theory, they may *only* be sets.

Comment: @celtschk Fair enough. In "naive set theory" though, one might consider certain things to be just "indivisible" elements, like "Tom" in the set of all boys' names. I am not arguing against ZF theory as a basis for mathematics, here, just not assuming ZF set theory is the context for the OP's question. It very well may be.

Answer (score 2):

The power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of the set $X$ is the set of all subsets of $X$. Now if $T = \{a,b\}$, then
$$
\mathcal{P}(A) = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\} \}\,.
$$
The set $\{\emptyset, a\}$  does not belong to $\mathcal{P}(A)$ because $\{\emptyset, a\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ means that $\{\emptyset, a\} \subset A$. But $\emptyset \notin A$ (this is different from $\emptyset \subset A$, which is always true). Similarly $\{\emptyset, b\} \notin \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: Does that mean that my teacher made a mistake by writing {Ø,{a}? Is that simply not possible?

Comment: @ABCCode yes, it looks like a mistake to me.

Comment: Ok, but what about the last bit. {Ø,{Ø}}} how is that made? And {Ø} by it self can be a power ser, but Ø by itself cant be a power set right?

Comment: $\{ \emptyset, \{a\}\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ is not possible because it requires that $\emptyset \in A$ which is not true if $A = \{a,b\}$.

Comment: What about my previous comment? ^^

Comment: $\emptyset$ can't be powerset because for every set $X$ it is true that $\emptyset \subset X$. Thus $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ for every set $X$. The set $\{\emptyset \}$ can be a power set though: it's the power set of the empty set.